# Notation in Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I am learning about the covariant derivative in semi-Riemannian manifolds, and came across some notation that I can't seem to make sense of.
For context, let $(M,g)$ be a semi-Riemannian manifold and $p \in M$. The Levi-Civita connection $\nabla_{\xi}$ at $p$ satisfies the product rule:

For all $f \in C_p^{\infty}$, all $\xi \in T_pM$ the tangent space, and all $\eta$ a $C^\infty$ vector field in a neighbourhood of $p$

$$
\nabla_{\xi}(f \cdot \eta)=\partial _{\xi} f \cdot \eta |_p+f(p)\cdot \nabla_{\xi}\eta.
$$

My question is what is the meaning of the term $\eta |_p$? Since $\eta$ maps $M$ to the tangent bundle $TM$ is it just the image of $p$ under $\eta$?

Or is it related to writing $\eta$ in the form

$$
\eta=\sum_{i=1}^n\eta^i(x(p))\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}|_p
$$
for a chart $x: U\to V$ and smooth functions $\eta^i: V \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It is just the value of $\eta$ at $p$.

Comment: Why is there a $\nabla$ inside $\nabla_{\xi}(f \cdot \nabla)$? Shouldn’t it be $\eta$?

Comment: For what it's worth, diff geo notation frequently does not explicitly say where an expression is being evaluated. For instance, if one is being very picky, in the equation you've written, they're missing $|_p$ in three places; one on the left hand side, one after $\partial_\xi f$, and one after $\nabla_\xi \eta$.